# In the hCalendar microformat, what markup is allowed in a description?

Tags: xhtml, microformats, hcalendar

I am working on a calendar application that outputs a list of events in [hCalendar format](http://microformats.org/wiki/hcalendar). This includes an element that has a class of "`description`" which should be used for the event's description. My question is, **what markup is allowed in my hCalendar event's description?**

I found one example on the hCalendar website that showed a description with `<br />` tags in it, but every other example was brief and had no additional markup in the description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as Microformats are concerned, you can use any valid HTML markup in the description (and everywhere else).

However, the [iCalendar](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2445#section-4.8.1.5) format, which is often used for extraction of hCalendars, only allows plain text in the description.

Use any markup you need, but be prepared that Microformat parsers will convert it to plain text, so likely only `<br>`, `<p>` will work, and other elements will have no effect.